# How to decode the token of a Basic Auth request

Tags: rust, basic-authentication, actix-web

I have this code:

```
#[get("/devices")]
async fn devices(req: HttpRequest) -> Result<impl Responder, Error> {

    let devices_data = vec![
        Device { id_device: 123, speed: 65.4, fuel: 75.2 },
        Device { id_device: 456, speed: 70.2, fuel: 80.0 },
    ];

    if let Some(auth_header) = req.headers().get("Authorization") {
        if let Ok(auth_str) = auth_header.to_str() {
            println!("Authorization Header: {}", auth_str);
        }
    }
        Ok(web::Json(devices_data ))

}
```

In the println I get the "Basic (big token string)" token. How can I decode that token in order to get the user and the password? What would be the code that than functions needs?

**EDIT**

This is the code I used with the http_auth_basic:

```
if let Some(auth_header) = req.headers().get("Authorization") {
    if let Ok(auth_str) = auth_header.to_str() {
        println!("Authorization Header: {}", auth_str);

        let auth_header_value = String::from(auth_str);
        let credentials = Credentials::from_header(auth_header_value).unwrap();

        println!("Username: {}", credentials.user_id);
        println!("Password: {}", credentials.password);

    }
}
```

And this is the error I got:

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidUtf8Value("invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 22")
```

It's wierd, looks like the code in the documentation.

Comment: There's nothing complicated about HTTP basic auth, you can find all relevant information on wikipedia and MDN (and a more exhaustive version in RFC 7617). Ignoring the `WWW-Authenticate` flow, the value is just the prefix `Basic `, followed by the username and password concatenated with a `:`, encoded in ascii (/ utf8), and encoded in base64. So you can just apply the reverse operations to decode.

Comment: https://docs.rs/http-auth-basic/latest/http_auth_basic/

Comment: I did use that package (http_auth_basic) but got this error: ```called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidUtf8Value("invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 22")```

Comment: @joegsuero You'll have to show the code you wrote for http_auth_basic if you want help debugging it. We can't see your screen.

Comment: @joegsuero The error combined with the code suggests that the provided base64-encoded credentials don't contain a valid UTF-8 sequence.